# How to prove that the set $A = \left\{ {p:{p^2} < 2,p \in {\Bbb Q^+}} \right\}$ has no greatest element?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

More specifically, I have to find a $q$ in $A$ such that $q$ is larger than any $p$ in $A$.

The only thing I can think of is using (${2 - {p^2}}$) somehow, or ${(p+x)^2}<2$, but other than that I don't know how to proceed. This exercise is taken from the very first chapter of Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. Quoting the exercise:

> *To do this, we associate with each rational $p > 0$ the number:*
>     $$q = p - \frac{{{p^2} - 2}}{{p + 2}} = \frac{{2p + 2}}{{p + 2}}$$

But he didn't explain how he came up with that number.

The only thing I've thought of is the following procedure:

$$\eqalign{
  & {p^2} + (2 - {p^2}) = 2 \Rightarrow {p^2} + (\frac{{2 - {p^2}}}{2}) < 2,{\text{ and since }}2 - {p^2}{\text{ is always positive,}}  \cr 
  & {p^2} < \left[ {{p^2} + (\frac{{2 - {p^2}}}{2})} \right] < 2  \cr 
  & {\text{Therefore, let }}q = \sqrt {{p^2} + (\frac{{2 - {p^2}}}{2})} ,{\text{ then:}}  \cr 
  & p < q < \sqrt 2  \cr} $$

However, my result doesn't necessarily belong to ${\Bbb Q}$. I wonder how did he obtain the value of $q$ in the book.

EDIT: Feel free to point out if there are more appropriate tags for this question.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to prove this for the subset of **integers** satisfying $p^2<2$?  Do you not think that you are looking for rational numbers instead?  Surely $\{z~:~z^2<2,z\in\Bbb Z\}=\{-1,0,1\}$ and $\{z~:~z^2<2,z\in\Bbb Z^+\}=\{1\}$...

Comment: I think you are confusing the integers $\mathbb Z$ with the rationals $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl Yes! I already corrected it.

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right, I already changed it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to figure out how he came up with it?  Isn't it enough to know it works?

Comment: To answer the title, and assuming you know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, just pick any $q \in (p, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and show that $q \in A$. However, the body of the question appears to be asking something different (how to explicitly construct a simple such $q$).

Comment: Let $x \in A$ and $\varepsilon = 2 - x^{2}$, then one should be able to pick an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that $x+\frac{\varepsilon}{N} \in A$.

Comment: @fleablood For me it really really really bothered me that I couldn't derive myself such an **obvious** mathematical fact. So at some point it because a personal problem and I just had to do it to know I was worthy of doing maths (yea it bothered me a lot XD). But also, I felt that I knew that Rudin didn't conjure magic so I became intensely curious what the trick/magic was. I was also genuinely curious what it takes to do rigorous mathematics and it seemed to be the first thing in an analysis book, so I tried it. After some pain I got something that made me satisfied.

Comment: What example number is it in the textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudin was most likely using facts about linear fractional transformations.

Let $S > 0$, $K > 0$ with $K^2 > S$

Set $F(x) = (S + Kx)/(K + x)$

IF $p > 0$ AND $p^2 < S$ THEN $p < F(p)$ AND $[F(p)]^2 < S$

PROOF

Since $F(x) = x + (S - x^2)/(K + x)$, it is clear that $p < F(p)$.

$[F(p)]^2 < S$ iff $S^2 + 2KSp + K^2p^2 < SK^2 +2KSp + Sp^2$ iff

$(K^2 -S) p^ 2 < SK^2 -S^2$ iff

$p^2 < (SK^2 -S^2)/(K^2 -S)$

But you can easily see that $(SK^2 -S^2)/(K^2 -S) = S$.

Comment: linear fractional transformations? is this really something one would know **before** analysis? I'm puzzled.

Comment: The OP asked how Dr. W. Rudin (May 2, 1921 – May 20, 2010) came up with the value for $q$, and I gave a shot at it. Of course it might have been something totally obvious to him, not requiring any explanation. His book with no pictures is terse and pithy, leaving plenty to the reader to digest,

Comment: What example number is it in the textbook?

Answer (score 9):

To show that $A$ has no greatest element, you have to show that **there is no** $q\in A$ which is greater than any $p\in A$, the opposite of your first line.

If $p^2<2$, we take the number $q=p+\frac{2-p^2}{p+2}=2\frac{p+1}{p+2}$. Then $p<q$ and $q^2=4\frac{(p+1)^2}{(p+2)^2}$. From $p^2<2$ you can infer $\frac{(p+1)^2}{(p+2)^2}<\frac{1}{2}$, so $q^2<2$.

This shows that to every rational $p<2$ we can associate $q=2\frac{p+1}{p+2}$, which will also be rational, and satisfying $p<q$, $q^2<2$, so $p$ is not the largest rational with this property.

---

As to where $q=p+\frac{2-p^2}{p+2}$ comes from: We are basically trying to find a root of $t^2-2$, by starting with some non-root $p$ and trying to make a better approximation to $\sqrt{2}$.

Note that the equation $q=p+\frac{2-p^2}{p+2}$ is equivalent to
$$(p^2-2)+(p+2)(q-p)=0$$
In other words, $q$ is a root of $t\mapsto (p^2-2)+(p+2)(t-p)$, which is the line which passes through $(p,p^2-2)$ with slope $(p+2)$. If you look at this line, and compare it with the graph of $t\mapsto t^2-2$, you will see that the intersection of the line and the $x$-axis will be closer to $\sqrt{2}$, and still smaller because $p+2>p+\sqrt{2}=\frac{2-p^2}{\sqrt{2}-p}$ (and this is the slope of the secant of the graph of $t^2-2$ passing through $(p,p^2-2)$ and $(\sqrt{2},0)$).

In fact, the slope $(p+2)$ works to make the inequalities in the exercise easier to deal with, but any number greater than $p+\sqrt{2}$ would work as well. Indeed, if $\alpha>p+\sqrt{2}$ and $(p^2-2)+\alpha(q-p)=0$, then
$$q=p+\frac{2-p^2}{\alpha}$$
so $q>p$, and
$$q<p+\frac{2-p^2}{p+\sqrt{2}}=p+(\sqrt{2}-p)=\sqrt{2}$$
i.e., $q^2<2$. If we choose $\alpha$ rational (so we'd need to know in advance more-or-less how much $\sqrt{2}$ is), then $q$ given as above will also be rational.

Comment: What example number is it in the textbook?

Answer (score 1):

I think he came up with it by endless division of guessing the square root.

$p <q $

and $p^2 <q^2< 2$  (but symmetrically we want the opposite if $p^2 > 2$

$q^2 - p^2 =(q+p)(q-p)<2 - p^2$

$q< p + \frac {2-p^2}{p+q} $

$q < p - \frac {p^2-2}{p+q}=\frac {qp+2}{p+q}$

$q $ can be anything that satisfies that.

Meh.... $q =p - \frac {p^2-2}{p+2}=\frac {2p+2}{p+2}$ makes the math easy.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share to you how I think Rudin did his magic in a more logical/principled way.

So what we want is to show that for any $p \in A = \{ p \in Q_+ : 0<p^2 <2\}$ we can **always** find a larger $q \in A$. The way I thought of it is that we want a $q = p+\epsilon, \epsilon>0$ such that:

$$ 0<p<(p+\epsilon)^2 = p^2 + 2 \epsilon p + \epsilon^2< 2$$

if you make $\epsilon$ the subject its really difficult to come up with a way to have its solution not involving square roots as you might have noticed. I realized that was really annoying and that was the issue. So with that intuition in mind I tried re-writing $p^2 + 2 \epsilon p + \epsilon^2$ so that maybe with some inspiration I could get rid of the term $\epsilon^2$. The first thing I tried was to write it without any squares at all it by factor $\epsilon$ and $p$. This lead to:

$$ p^2 + 2 \epsilon p + \epsilon^2 = p^2 + \epsilon p + \epsilon p+ \epsilon^2= p(p+\epsilon)+\epsilon (p+\epsilon)$$

then I stared at this equation and wondered if there was anything else I knew about the problem so that I could "get rid" of **one** of the terms in $\epsilon (p+\epsilon)$ with the goal of removing the $\epsilon^2$ and maybe having something in the rationals for sure. Doing that I noticed involved some type of knowledge of $q = p+\epsilon$ or $\epsilon$. I knew $\epsilon>0$ which was not  terribly helpful but I noticed that for sure $p+ \epsilon < 2$ (by drawing some diagrams, then I discovered I could "cheat" by using the fact that I knew $q = p+ \epsilon < \sqrt 2 < 2$ to justify it to myself, though you can easily prove it by contradiction if you want a rigorous reason). At this point I noticed that by using the inequality I actually introduced knew knowledge to the problem and not just playing around with the rules of algebra, which was quintessential because otherwise things are just re-writting things in terms of others for hours as it happened to me.

Anyway this lead to realization that I could indeed remove the $\epsilon^2$ as follows:

$$ p(p + \epsilon) + \epsilon(p+\epsilon) < p^2 + p \epsilon + 2 \epsilon $$

hoping that it wouldn't lead to an upper bound that wasn't too high/large, since I introduced the fact $p+\epsilon < 2$ which is an upper bound (lets hope its not too large!). Right now I intuitively though I bet this will work because I indeed can control how small I make $\epsilon$ in order to make $p \epsilon + 2 \epsilon$ sufficiently small. I proceeded by just enforcing that it was **indeed smaller than 2**:

$$ q = (p+\epsilon)^2 < p^2 + p \epsilon + 2 \epsilon < 2 $$

then I proceeded to make $\epsilon$ the subject to get:

$$ 0 < \epsilon < \frac{2 - p^2}{p+2} = -\frac{p^2 - 2}{p+2}$$

at this point I realized that choosing $\frac{2 - p^2}{p+2}$ would make **the upper bound** (introduced after using the fact $q =p+\epsilon<2$) equal to 2 but if we applied it to $q = p+\epsilon$ itself then since it was **strictly less** than the upper bound, that it we would be safe and have $q$ still be less than $2$. That happened to be correct and so I choose that value $\epsilon = -\frac{p^2 - 2}{p+2} $.

Notice however that any rational constant should work to bound $p+\epsilon$ as long as its constant. Though, larger bounds would obviously require smaller $epsilon$'s (which is fine as long they are rationals).

Comment: how do you know $p + \epsilon < 2$?

Comment: What example number is it in the textbook?

Comment: it is example 1.1