# Certain step that $\{x\in \mathbb{Q}\mid x^2<2\}$ has no supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}\mid x^2<2\}$. Then $A$ has no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.

The proof I read is: ''If it did, say $r$, then it can be shown that $r^2=2$. But we know that there is no such rational number.''

**Question:** How can it be shown that $r^2=2$ in the first sentence?

If $B$ is a set, and if $\sup B=k$, wouldn't it mean that $y\leq k$ for all $y\in B$ and there is no upper bound lesser than $k$? Or, is it using the fact that: ''There exists a real number $x$, such that $x^2=2$'', then replace $x$ by $r$, as supremum is unique?

Comment: I'd rather choose your first idea, not using any knowledge of $\mathbb R$ or $\sqrt2$ (see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335763)).

Comment: @AnneBauval, yeah I prefer avoiding any knowledge of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\sqrt{2}$. In the answer in your link, if one assumes by contradiction that $m/n\in\mathbb{Q}$ is the supremum of $A$, how to prove by cases that $m/n<2$ and $m/n>2$ imply contradiction? For example, if $m/n<2$, what should the next step be without using the Archimedean property?

Comment: (All the $m/n$ in your comment must of course be replaced by $(m/n)^2$).  If $x^2<2$ (and $x>0$), $$y:=\frac2{\frac1x+\frac x2}$$ will be $>x$ and still $y^2<2$ (this is [Heron's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)).

Comment: Similarly, if $u^2>2$ (and $u>0$),$$v=\frac{u+\frac2u}2$$will be $<u$ and still $v^2>2.$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists $r=\sup\ A$. In order to show $r^2=2$, let us show that none of $r^2<2$ and $r^2>2$ can happen.

Let us suppose $r^2<2$. In particular, $2-r^2>0$.  By Archimedian property, there is $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$, such that:

$$n\cdot (2-r^2)>2\cdot r+1.$$

This implies
\begin{align*} 
\frac{1}{n}<\frac{2-r^2}{2\cdot r+1}.
\end{align*}
Hence, using that

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n},$$
it follows

\begin{align*} 
\left(r+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2&=r^2+\frac{2\cdot r}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&\leq r^2+\frac{2\cdot r}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\\
&=r^2+\frac{2\cdot r+1}{n}\\
&<r^2+(2\cdot r+1)\cdot \frac{2-r^2}{2\cdot r+1}\\
&=r^2+2-r^2\\
&=2.
\end{align*}

Since

$$r+\frac{1}{n}\in \mathbb Q\quad \textrm{and}\quad \left(r+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2<2$$
one has

$$r+\frac{1}{n}\in A.$$

This contradicts the fact that $r$ is an upper bound of $A$ for

$$r<r+\frac{1}{n}.$$

Now, it is left to show $r^2>2$ can not happen. If $r^2>2$, then $r^2-2>0$ and by Archimedian property, there exists $n\in \mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ such that

$$
n\cdot (r^2-2)>2\cdot r.
$$
This imples

$$
r^2-\frac{2\cdot r}{n}>2.
$$
Notice also
$$
r^2-\frac{2\cdot r}{n}>2\implies r-\frac{2}{r}>\frac{2}{n}>\frac{1}{n}\implies r-\frac{1}{n}>0.
$$
Now,
\begin{align*} 
\left(r-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2&=r^2-\frac{2\cdot r}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}>r^2-\frac{2\cdot r}{n}>2
\end{align*}

Since $r=\sup\ A$, there exists $x_0\in A$ such that

$$r-\frac{1}{n}<x_0.$$
Since $r-\frac{1}{n}>0$, it follows

$$x_0^2>\left(r-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2>2.$$
This contradicts $x_0\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, in the answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335763), if one assumes by contradiction that $r∈\Bbb Q$
is the supremum of $A
,$ here is how to prove by cases that $r^2<2$
and $r^2>2$ both
imply contradiction,  without using the Archimedean property:

- If $x^2<2$
  (and $x>0$
  ),
  $$y:=\frac2{{\frac1x}+\frac x2}$$
  will be $>x$
  and still $y^2<2$
  (this is [Heron's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)). So, $r^2$ cannot be $<2.$
- Similarly, if $u^2>2$
  (and $u>0$
  ),
  $$v:=\frac{u+\frac2u}2$$
  will be $<u$
  and still $v^2>2.$ So, $r^2$ cannot be $>2.$